# Error receiving notifications from Journey Builder in android with SDK v6.3.4

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush, android, push-notification

Hello everyone, I’d implemented Marketing Cloud sdk on android to receive push notifications.

The notifications are working perfect from Mobile Push, however, when we send it from Journey Builder, the notification arrives to the devices BUT it doesn’t show up (it seems that the SDK (v6.3.4) is not able to launch it.

Has anyone faced with a similar scenario that can help me please?

Comment: The SDK makes no distinction between a push message sent from Mobile Push vs. a push message sent from Journey Builder.  Can you please share the LogCat output or other supporting evidence for "notification arrives to the devices BUT it doesn't show up"?

Comment: Still waiting on Logs.

Comment: Is this still an open issue?  If not, please either answer your own question with how you fixed your implementation issue or delete the question :)